# Какой знак предпочтительнее?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-варианта

Тире vs двоеточие vs запятая vs точка с запятой? Как правильно?
Я думаю, 1-й и 2-й – правильны, а 3-й и 4-й – отнюдь не правильные таки-с.

1. Ой, извини, совсем **забыла:** завтра не смогу. Давай встретимся в один из дней на следующей неделе. Я тебе напишу.
2. Ой, извини, совсем **забыла —** завтра не смогу. <...>
3. Ой, извини, совсем **забыла,** завтра не смогу.  <...>
4. Ой, извини, совсем **забыла;** завтра не смогу. <...>
5. Ой, извини, совсем **забыла.** Завтра не смогу. <...>

Comment: Вижу, что добавили пятый вариант. Тогда надо и в текст вопроса внести изменения.

Comment: 3 вариант, незачем перегружать синтаксис, совсем забыла - вводное. "Уже миновало две недели пребывания Виктора, и он, притаясь, не думал напоминать об отправлении; а старик, чрезвычайно довольный его обществом, казалось, совсем забыл, что Виктор не домашний."

Comment: Вариант с двоеточием должен содержать высказывание или какое-то расширение понятия. 
"Да бишь виноват!.. совсем забыл: ведь вы, кавалеристы, народ модный, воспитанный, шаркуны!" Тут явно не тянет на расширение, обычное действие - я завтра не смогу. Либо - "забыла ему сказать: завтра на смогу", - какой-то такой вариант. То есть "передай ему эти слова, которые я забыла сказать".

Comment: 5 вариант тоже можно использовать, остальные с тире и точкой запятой сомнительны, но может в какой-то ситуации нужно так.

Comment: В 3 всё-таки не вводное, а однородное сказуемое с определением - самый простой вариант.

Comment: @Буратино Да, маловато для раскрытия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Тема связана с выбором знака** в бессоюзном сложном предложении **(БСП).**

1. *Ой, извини, совсем забыла: **завтра не смогу.***

**Двоеточие** как основной знак. Значение ближе к **изъяснительному**  (что забыла сказать), но при этом содержит пояснительную информацию с указанием причины. Интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю (неполное понижение голоса и подчёркнутая пауза).

2. *Ой, извини, совсем забыла — **завтра не смогу.***

**Тире** может заменять двоеточие. Интонация присоединительная, нет интонационного предупреждения, пауза меньше. Подходит для разговорного стиля.

3. *Ой, извини, совсем забыла, **завтра не смогу**.*

**Запятая** тоже  может заменять двоеточие в разговорном стиле, тогда пауза еще меньше, она ближе к произносительной.

**[Розенталь, пункт 3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150)**

Примечание. При отсутствии оттенка предупреждения в начале бессоюзного сложного предложения данного типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится запятая: Слышу, земля задрожала (Н.).

4. *Ой, извини, совсем забыла; **завтра не смогу.***

**Точка с запятой** не подойдет, нет оснований для применения этого знака. Обычно используется в распространенных предложениях с разной тематикой (стиль не разговорный).

5. *Ой, извини, совсем забыла. **Завтра не смогу**.*

Это **два предложения**, такое оформление возможно, если нужно обозначить не паузу, а остановку в речи.  Смысл примерно такой: *Ой, извини, совсем забыла. Завтра-то я не смогу.*

Comment: Причина? Почему забыла?

Comment: Точка не очень, потому что "Ой, извини, совсем забыла" не самостоятельное, нет законченной мысли.

Comment: Спасибо, я учла ваши замечания и поправила текст ответа.

Comment: Вообще не вижу причину. Причина должна быть того, что непосредственно перед двоеточием. Мне вариант с запятой кажется самым естественным. Само по себе предложение относится к разговорному стилю (люди разговаривают).

Comment: Из-за незаконченности мысли хочется многоточие поставить: *Ой, извини, совсем забыла... Завтра не смогу.* Вот это уже удачно. Вариант с двоеточием нестандартный, так не говорят. Ещё можно говорить об удачности вариантов. Что хуже, что лучше...

Comment: я тоже думаю, что кусок "ой, извини, совсем забыла" - бессодержательный и по сути штамп-паразит, просто для создания видимости причины, когда её по сути нет. Штамп-поразит не несет никакой полезной информации, при том, что это именно коммуникативные стандартные конструкции, а не что-то творческое.

Comment: "Ой, извини, совсем забыла" может быть штампом, а может соответствовать реальной ситуации. Причем второе второе более вероятно. Персонаж не отказывается совсем от встречи, а переносит ее. А конкретный знак  (при одной и той же СЕМАНТИКЕ)  соответствует паузе в устной речи. И во всех случаях сообщения   отличаются именно этим, а понижение тона перед паузой присутствует везде.  Грамматика и пунктуация – всё по правилам.

Comment: Что касается выбора, то наиболее подходящим знаком (по произношению и графике)  является тире, а потом запятая. Двоеточие  (в произносительном варианте и в таком предложении)  применяется реже.  Точка возможна, но маловероятна.

Comment: "Милая бабушка! пишу к вам по тяжелой почте, потому что третьего дня по экстра-почте не успел, ибо ездил на железные воды и, виноват, совсем забыл, что там письма не принимают; боюсь, чтобы вы не стали беспокоиться, что одну почту нет письма." виноват, совсем забыл - это формы формального извинения. Совсем забыл без распространения, совсем забыл что? Совсем забыл сказать, совсем забыл, что... или еще как-то - это чисто штамп. Если штамп - то точка, или восклицательный, или многоточие, если дальше идет согласование с основной значимой частью - то запятая.

Comment: А без всего это, это какой-то предикат с дополнением. Совсем забыл, насмерть убил, быстро бежал... Так даже в ответ не скажешь никому.